# Android Q . FileChooser SecurityException

Tags: android, permissions

I'm pretty new in Android programming. I want to open a directory an get persistent read access on it. I add the flag `FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION` to the intent.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, null), MY_REQUEST);
```

On the `onActivityResult`Methode, I fetch the `data` to get the `uri` like

```
Uri uri = data.getData()
cUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(uri,
DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri));
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(cUri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

I got an `SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found`
But the permissions are set as intent.flag.

Why I got this error and how can I avoid it?

Thanks 
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I add the flag FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION to the intent

That is not what that flag is for.

> On the onActivityResultMethode, I fetch the data to get the uri like

Delete `cUri`. Use `uri` with `takePersistableUriPermission()`.

Comment: Thanks...this works...so there is no need to set the `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`?

Comment: @FischerPeter: Correct. You use those flags when you already have rights to some `Uri` and you wish to pass those rights along to another app. For example, if you are using `FileProvider` to give you a `Uri` to a file, and you want to pass that `Uri` to another app via `ACTION_VIEW`, you would use `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to give the other app the rights to access the content. In this case, you are *receiving* the `Uri`, and your `Intent` does not have a `Uri`, so the flags are not relevant.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your excellent answer...I'm sorry, I'm so new, that I can't vote for Your answer